# Gridview refresh problem

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

i would like to refresh a gridview after I add a record to database. how can i do that? i try to get all records again, however it throws an error.

Error : An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Line : DSPContext5.SaveChanges();

```
DSPContext5 = new DSPEntities();
int inst_id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlInstructors.SelectedItem.Value);
int course_id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCourseList.SelectedItem.Value);
var query = new Critics { critic = txtComment.Text, instructor_id = inst_id, course_id = course_id, member_id = member_id };
DSPContext5.AddToCritics(query);
DSPContext5.SaveChanges();

DSPContext2 = new DSPEntities();

var query = from c in DSPContext2.CriticsList
            where c.instructor_id == inst_id
            select new { c.id, c.courseName, c.studentName, c.studentEmail, c.critic };
GridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: where is the exception message?

Comment: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. "

Answer (score 0):

InnerException is one of the properties of the Exception that is thrown.   You need to loop through the inner exceptions to get the full details for the exception being thrown.

Once you post those details, we should be able to get to the underlying problem.